# Change Outlook date/time display to relative?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook, the date/time shows up like so:

> Tue 3/13/2012 5:53 PM

Such as for "Date Received".

On various other programs/systems, they allow you to set the date/time display to be relative like this:

> 3 minutes ago

(For example if the time was 5:53 PM compared to above, thus 3 minutes ago)

Other examples:

> 1 hour, 4 minutes ago

Or:

> Yesterday, 3:20 PM

Or if it's not a recent date, it typically shows up like normal:

> 2/13/2012 5:53 PM

PHP has relative formats: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Can Outlook do this (without add-ons)?

I found this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-your-date-format-HA010210018.aspx

But it wants me to change my Windows settings. I only want to change Outlook.

Or would this be possible in Windows 7?

I believe Thunderbird has an "Age in days" feature.